# How to apply absolute rotation angles to GameObject with respect to Local Axis in unity3d?

Tags: rotation, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I try to use Transform.Rotate() , But this is relative to previous rotation values.How to apply absolute rotation in Local axis.

Thanks

Comment: manual:   eulerAngles

Comment: those are applying in world space axis

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by apply absolute rotation? Pretty sure you are looking for transform.localEulerAngles